# Open buffer created by run-python in the current window

Tags: spacemacs, python

I recently started using spacemacs, and have a newbie question about modifying the way `run-python` works.

When I execute `run-python`, a new buffer is opened in a different window. I'd like to change it so that it opens the newly created buffer in the current window.

Using `find-function` I found the source for `run-python`:

```
(defun run-python (&optional cmd dedicated show)
  "Run an inferior Python process.

Argument CMD defaults to `python-shell-calculate-command' return
value.  When called interactively with `prefix-arg', it allows
the user to edit such value and choose whether the interpreter
should be DEDICATED for the current buffer.  When numeric prefix
arg is other than 0 or 4 do not SHOW.

For a given buffer and same values of DEDICATED, if a process is
already running for it, it will do nothing.  This means that if
the current buffer is using a global process, the user is still
able to switch it to use a dedicated one.

Runs the hook `inferior-python-mode-hook' after
`comint-mode-hook' is run.  (Type \\[describe-mode] in the
process buffer for a list of commands.)"
  (interactive
   (if current-prefix-arg
       (list
        (read-shell-command "Run Python: " (python-shell-calculate-command))
        (y-or-n-p "Make dedicated process? ")
        (= (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg) 4))
     (list (python-shell-calculate-command) nil t)))
  (get-buffer-process
   (python-shell-make-comint
    (or cmd (python-shell-calculate-command))
    (python-shell-get-process-name dedicated) show)))
```

and the source for `python-shell-make-comint`

```
(defun python-shell-make-comint (cmd proc-name &optional show internal)
  "Create a Python shell comint buffer.
CMD is the Python command to be executed and PROC-NAME is the
process name the comint buffer will get.  After the comint buffer
is created the `inferior-python-mode' is activated.  When
optional argument SHOW is non-nil the buffer is shown.  When
optional argument INTERNAL is non-nil this process is run on a
buffer with a name that starts with a space, following the Emacs
convention for temporary/internal buffers, and also makes sure
the user is not queried for confirmation when the process is
killed."
  (save-excursion
    (python-shell-with-environment
      (let* ((proc-buffer-name
              (format (if (not internal) "*%s*" " *%s*") proc-name)))
        (when (not (comint-check-proc proc-buffer-name))
          (let* ((cmdlist (split-string-and-unquote cmd))
                 (interpreter (car cmdlist))
                 (args (cdr cmdlist))
                 (buffer (apply #'make-comint-in-buffer proc-name proc-buffer-name
                                interpreter nil args))
                 (python-shell--parent-buffer (current-buffer))
                 (process (get-buffer-process buffer))
                 ;; Users can override the interpreter and args
                 ;; interactively when calling `run-python', let-binding
                 ;; these allows having the new right values in all
                 ;; setup code that is done in `inferior-python-mode',
                 ;; which is important, especially for prompt detection.
                 (python-shell--interpreter interpreter)
                 (python-shell--interpreter-args
                  (mapconcat #'identity args " ")))
            (with-current-buffer buffer
              (inferior-python-mode))
            (when show (display-buffer buffer))
            (and internal (set-process-query-on-exit-flag process nil))))
        proc-buffer-name))))
```

Based on the following snippets of documentation taken from the definition of `display-buffer`

```
"Optional argument ACTION, if non-nil, should specify a buffer
display action of the form (FUNCTIONS . ALIST).  FUNCTIONS is
either an \"action function\" or a possibly empty list of action
functions.  ALIST is a possibly empty \"action alist\"."

"Action functions and the action they try to perform are:
 `display-buffer-same-window' -- Use the selected window."
```

I thought by changing the line `(when show (display-buffer buffer))` to `(when show (display-buffer buffer (cons '(display-buffer-same-window) '())))` I could get the behavior I wanted, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Questions:

1. Is my understanding of how the code works incorrect? If so, how?
2. Is modifying and saving the buffer sufficient to change the behavior of the `run-python` command?
3. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: For 2., the answer is "no", unless you kill and restart Emacs. To have the modified code take effect in the same session (i.e. without killing/restarting), you either need to reevaluate the function or load the `.el` file or byte-compile the `.el` file and load the `.elc` file. Emacs needs to have the new function in its memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist 
'("^\\*Python\\*$" . (display-buffer-same-window)))
```