# `run-python` cannot hide *Python* buffer

Tags: python, mark, save-excursion

When running

```
(defun my/run-python ()
  (interactive)
  
  (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
      (with-current-buffer buf
        (save-mark-and-excursion
          (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) nil nil)
          )
        ))
)
```

I cannot hide `*Python*` from showing. It looks like `show` arg is ignored as evidenced from [Open buffer created by run-python in the current window](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/57776/20237)

```
(defun run-python (&optional cmd dedicated show)
```

I even tried using `save-mark-and-excursion` as a work-around but to no avail.

And `debug-on-entry` for `python-shell-make-comint` shows a compiled function
[image]

Using Emacs 27.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in Emacs 30.0.50 (more-or-less current upstream from the git repo) or 28.2 (the most recent released version).

Comment: Ok, will give newer version a try

Comment: You should also try with `emacs -q` to eliminate the possibility that your init file is doing something to cause this.